# Are Scott Pruitt's problems over after his resignation?

Tags: united-states, ethics

Scott Pruitt resigned because of numerous ethical scandal investigations.

Do the investigations continue?

Does resigning clear him of all those investigations?  If he misused public funds, is he still accountable?

Comment: ...asking for a friend.

Comment: According to his resignation letter, the reason was because ["the unrelenting attacks on me personally, my family, are unprecedented and have taken a sizable toll on all of us"](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2018/07/05/scott-pruitts-full-resignation-letter-to-president-trump.html). No admission of wrongdoing is the first step in a solid legal defense...

Comment: @LShaver Or he's actually just that delusional.

Comment: It would not be surprising that if there were charges filed, that Trump would pardon him, unless Trump and Pruitt had a "falling out".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Pruitt is currently under [investigation](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/heres-a-scorecard-of-the-scott-pruitt-investigations/2018/07/02/30a41254-7e25-11e8-a63f-7b5d2aba7ac5_story.html?utm_term=.29bec6287bba) for upwards of 13 charges. At least one of those investigations, the one in the House Oversight Committee, [will continue](https://www.cnn.com/politics/live-news/epa-scott-pruitt-resigns/index.html). The EPA Inspector General, the Office of Management and Budget, the Government Accountability Office, the U.S. Office of Special Consul, and the Senate all have investigations. None of these have commented yet, but expect that they will all continue, and Pruitt can still be held accountable for breaking the law.

Comment: @DJohnM I'd suggest avoiding speculation on that front. Figuring out what Mueller's investigation is currently doing, outside a few known facts, is like reading tea leaves.